# Verification that Chebyshev's Inequality Holds for $f(x) = \begin{cases} -2e^{-2x}+2e^{-x} &: 0 <x\\ 0 &: \text{else} \end{cases}$

Tags: probability

I have the pdf $f(x) = \begin{cases}
-2e^{-2x}+2e^{-x} &: 0 <x\\
0 &: \text{else}
\end{cases}$

and I want to verify that Chebyshev's Inequality for holds for $k=2$.

After finding the mean and variance I have

$\mu = \frac{3}{2}$, $\sigma^2=\frac{5}{4} \implies \sigma=\sqrt{\frac{5}{4}}=1.118$,$1-\frac{1}{k^2}=1-\frac{1}{4}=\frac{3}{4}$ and then

$\mu \pm k\sigma$ which gives me $\frac{3}{2}-2\left(1.18\right)=-0.736$ and $\frac{3}{2}+2\left(1.118\right)=3.736$

So I have $P(-0.736 < X < 3.736)\geq 0.75$

but to verify this I need $\int^{3.736}_{-0.736}f(x)dx$ which does not seem correct.

Could anyone provide some feedback? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to remember that the pdf is only defined for $0 < x$. So when checking that Chebyshev's Inequality holds, you only need to verify it for $\int_0^{3.736} f(x) dx$ which you can evaluate to $0.9528$ which is larger than $0.75$, so it does satisfy Chebyshev's Inequality.